# How to change font size on html tag- android

Tags: java, android

I got below response from server and i've load it on web view

```
<font size=\"7\"><font color=\"#000099\">Android sdk<\/font><br><\/font><div style=\"font-size: 10pt;\"><br><\/div>
```

i need to change the font size to that response and load on webview.

How to change the font size on html tags?

Answer (score 0):

you may use < small> for smaller text and < b> for bigget text, as  only supports color and face attributes.